# looker dev difference between PDT and regular DT

Tags: looker

LookerML question:
I have got this snowflake query which joins one static table (does not refresh) and one table that refreshes every day.
I want to pop this query into Looker and create a simple Looker dashboard using it.
Two options I think are available to me to do so:

1. Create view file and PDT but that would mean I need to add a trigger value and the data including the static table would refresh, right? - Isn't this very inefficient?
2. Create regular DT with the explore being a PDT?

Answer (score 1):

A derived table will be temporary and will not be written to the database.  Each time the dashboard is refreshed, a query will be rerun against your data source to extract data.

A persistent derived table will store the data results in a database, whilst using a persistent strategy to refreshing the data based on time or a data driven trigger.  If the persistent data already exists and is still valid, Looker will extract the results from the persisted data rather than creating a query against your source database.

Comment: Is a daily 'snapshot' of the data in the persisted table stored somewhere? Can I e.g. use the data for a time series comparison? Thank you for answering my question.

Comment: Yes the persisted table will be stored.  You configure where persisted data is stored when you set up you connection details.  There is an exception with snowflake if the connection is using oath, in which case pdt's are not supported.   Take a look at https://cloud.google.com/looker/docs/derived-tables